# ¿Como eliminar las filas de una jtable?me da este error al eliminar modelo.removeRow(x); = >Exception occurred in target VM: 374 >= 1<

Tags: java-swing

Tengo un porblema. Tengo una jtable donde debe mostrame las citas de cada medico, si yo cambio de medico pues me da sus citas y las del otro no me aparece.
En la practica si yo cambio de medico me duplica triplica o cuadriplica el dato mostrardo en la tabla pero en el arraylist solo hay 1 dato.
Entonces habia pensado en eliminar las lineas cada vez que cambie de doctor y limpiar la tbla, pero he probado varios codigo y no soy capz. os dejo mi idea y haber que os parece

```
 public void mostrarTabla() {
        if(modelo.getRowCount()!=0)
            for (int x =0; x<modelo.getRowCount()-1; x++){
               modelo.removeRow(x);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listaDoctoresG.size(); i++) {
            if (listaDoctoresG.get(i).getNombreDoctor().compareToIgnoreCase(cmbDoctor.getSelectedItem().toString()) == 0);
            Doctor doc = listaDoctoresG.get(i);
            for (int x = 0; x < doc.getListaCitas().size(); x++) {
                Cita c = doc.getListaCitas().get(x);
                int idC = c.getNumerocita();
                Paciente pac = c.getPac();
                Date fecha = c.getHora();
                modelo.addRow(new Object[]{idC, pac, fecha});
                tablaCitas.setModel(modelo);
            }
        }
    }
```

si en vez de modelo. lo que sea pongo tablaCitas tanpoco funciona.
Asi creo la tabla la principio de swinch pongio

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
```

luego inicio la tabla con este metodo

```
public void inicializartabla() {
        modelo.addColumn("Id cita");
        modelo.addColumn("Paciente");
        modelo.addColumn("Fecha");
        tablaCitas.setModel(modelo);
        JTextField f = new JTextField();
        f.setEditable(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < tablaCitas.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            tablaCitas.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(f));
        }
        TableColumnModel columnModel = tablaCitas.getColumnModel();
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(60);
        columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(300);
        listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Comment: Vuelve a mirar mi respuesta. Tienes un problema de diseño con el modelo. No tienes que ir pasándole cada cita. El modelo tiene que tener todos los datos que tiene que pintar en la tabla porque es la clase que va a usar la tabla para rellenarse, llamando a las funciones getRowCount, getColumnCount, getValueAt y getColumnName, sobrecargadas de la clase base AbstractTableModel. Al ejecutar repaint sobre la tabla, internamente llama a estas funciones para ir pintando las filas y columnas. Así que lo que tienes que hacer es pasarle la información (toda, no de elemento a elemento) y llamar a repaint

Comment: Yo lo he hecho tal cual me ha enseñado el profesor en un ejemplo jaja. No me queda claro que haccer con toda esa clase que has creado,

Comment: Esa clase o más o menos igual que esa debería ser tu clase modelo, personalizada y no usar un DefaultTableModel. Defines la tabla como haces, pero le asignas como modelo un objeto de esta clase de modelo personalizada. A ese modelo personalizado le pasas tu lista de citas y repintas la tabla. Eso es todo lo que tienes que hacer. Cuando quieras cambiar tu tabla, le pasas una nueva lista de citas al modelo, y vuelves a repintar tu tabla.

Comment: Mañana pruebo y te cuento que tal, pero ya te digo mi profesor me ha dicho que lo cree asi

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en cómo has definido el modelo para tu tabla. Por un lado tienes la tabla y por otro el modelo. El modelo tiene que tener siempre todos los datos que quieres mostrar en la tabla cada vez. Así que puedes hacer que el modelo contenga la lista, vector o como quieras, de citas. Desde fuera de la clase modelo, cuando seleccionas un doctor, generas la lista con sus citas y le pasas la lista completa al modelo, sustituyendo la lista que tenía antes entera, y después sobre la tabla, ejecutarías la función repaint. Algo como esto:

```
public class ItemsTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String [] columnNames = { "TuTitulo_Col0", "TuTitulo_Col1", "TuTitulo_Col2"};

    private Vector<Tu_Objeto_Citas> ItemsVector = null;

    //Con esta función estableces una nueva lista de citas para un doctor. La llamas
    //cada vez que quieres cambiar el contenido de toda la tabla.
    public void setNewItemsVector( Vector<Tu_Objeto_Citas> itemsVector) {
        ItemsVector = itemsVector;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ItemsVector != null ? ItemsVector.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( ItemsVector == null) {
            return "";
        }

        Tu_Objeto_Citas item = ItemsVector.elementAt( rowIndex);
        if( columnIndex == 0) {
            return "" + item.getTuCampoCol1();
        } else if( columnIndex == 1) {
            return "" + item.getTuCampoCol2();
        } else if( columnIndex == 2) {
            return "" + item.getTuCampoCol3();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

}
```

Al crear la tabla:

```
ItemsTableModel = new ItemsTableModel();
ItemsTable = new JTable( ItemsTableModel);
```

Y para rellenarla: tienes que generar en este caso un Vector de objetos Tu_Objeto_Citas con los datos que quieres mostrar en la tabla en cada columna. Una vez creado ese vector se lo pasarías al modelo:

```
ItemsTableModel.setNewItemsVector( tu_vector_de_citas_para_ese_doctor);
ItemsTable.repaint();
```

Para borrar la tabla:

```
ItemsTableModel.setNewItemsVector( null);
ItemsTable.repaint();
```

Comment: te pongo como he creado la tabla